# Not Found: /accounts/register/accounts/register

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-registration, django-custom-user

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/accounts/register
```

views.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from custom_user.forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.contrib import auth 
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
#Create your views here
def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, "login.html", c)

def about(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'about.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

@login_required
def userProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {'user': user}
    template = 'profile.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get['username', '']   
    password = request.POST.get['password', '']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HTTpResponseRedirect('account/login')
    else:
        return HTTpResponseRedirect('account/login')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect ('accounts/register_success.html')

    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', args)

def register_success(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/register_success.html')


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render(request, 'logout.html')
```

when i try to register a new user this error is raised . i manage to create my own custom registration form. i still cannot register any new user . is this error means that my registration form is not authenticate ? can someone explain why i get this error please ? im confused . help me please :(

urls.py :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from profiles import views as profiles_views
from contact import views as contact_views
from checkout import views as checkout_views
from register import views as register_views

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^$', profiles_views.home, name='home'),
     url(r'^profile/$', profiles_views.userProfile, name='profile'),
     url(r'^about/$', profiles_views.about, name='about'),
     url(r'^checkout/$', checkout_views.checkout, name='checkout'),
     url(r'^contact/$', contact_views.contact, name='contact'),
     url(r'^accounts/register/$', register_views.register, name='register'),
      url(r'^accounts/register_success/$', register_views.register_success, name='register_success'),
     url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
     url(r'^auth/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root= settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Form.valid() should be inside the post indentation